# Unable to get script to send and html to receive and show text via 'onclick'

Tags: javascript

I am just teaching myself coding and am stuck, please go easy on me as I am a newbie...... I would appreciate any help with my website...

I have created this code which works fine.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function swapImage3(id,primary,secondary,thirdly,fourthly,fifthly) {
    src=document.getElementById(id).src;
    if (src.match(primary)) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=secondary; 
      greeting='Click two';
    } else if (src.match(secondary)) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=thirdly;
      greeting='Click three';
    } else if (src.match(thirdly)) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=fourthly;
      greeting='Click four';
    } else if (src.match(fourthly)) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=fifthly;
      greeting='Click five';
    } else if (src.match(fifthly)) {
      document.getElementById(id).src=primary;
      greeting='Click one';
    }
  }
</script>

<body>

<div id="carousel_containerSL">
<div class="text14">                
<div id="slider3">
<div class="wrap">
<img id="three" 
     draggable="false" 
     src="images/COL1.jpg"   
     onclick="swapImage3('three', 'images/COL2.jpg', 'images/COL3.jpg',
                         'images/COL4.jpg', 'images/COL5.jpg', 
                         'images/COL1.jpg')"
     onmouseout="this.src='images/COL1.jpg'" 
     onclick="swapImage3(
<h3 class="captz">
<script>
   document.write ("greeting")
</script>
</h3>
```

Except...

...although my pictures rotate fine using 'onclick' and revert to the original onmousout, I have a total brain-fog regarding getting the text in the:

`document.write ("greeting")`

position at the bottom underneath each picture to rotate with the same onclicks... I am attempting to get it to read from variable:

```
greeting="Click"
```

in the top script... but I fear the is my mistake??...

So to clarify, I wish to change some text and get it to rotate with the pictures... I am running before I can walk, but everything else seems to work on my site except this...

Any help??? Please??

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but the best advice at this point is to learn to indent your code properly, which facilitates readability, which facilitates debugging and to set up your event handlers in JavaScript (`object.addEventListener(...)`), not HTML (`onclick=...`, `onmouseover=...`) and to not use `document.write()` at all. Instead inject your content into existing elements (like your `<h3>`) with `object.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I thought I did but I will try again in future

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write()`...ever. It is a very old way of adding content to a document while the document is being built. Using it after the document is built, which is what you are trying to do, will cause the existing document to be thrown away and an entirely new one to be written.  Instead use `innerHTML` or `textContent` to inject the content into the document (a.k.a. the "DOM").

Here's an example of how to structure the code with your click event working. I'm not sure what you were after with your mouseout function since it simply sets the image source to the same value that it already had.

```js
// When the document is loaded run the function called "init"
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init(){
  // This function will run as soon as the document is loaded and ready for interaction
  // Set up variables that will need to be used throughout the function
  // These variables will point to the HTML objects you need to interact with
  var img = document.getElementById("three");
  var h3 = document.querySelector("h3.captz");
  
  // Set up event handling functions:
  img.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
    swapImage3(e.target, 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/facebook-256.png', 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/facebook-256.png',
               'http://blueblots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/high-details-social-facebook-icon.jpg', 'http://wfarm4.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set113/badaf4a8.png', 'http://www.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Facebook-icon-26.png');
  });
  
  img.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){ 
    e.target.src='http://www.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Facebook-icon-26.png'
  });   
 
  function swapImage3(obj,primary,secondary,thirdly,fourthly,fifthly) {
    console.log(obj.src,primary,secondary,thirdly,fourthly,fifthly)
    var greeting = "";
    switch(obj.src){
    case primary:
        greeting = 'two';
        break;
    case secondary:
        greeting = 'three';
        break;
    case thirdly:
        greeting = 'four';
        break;        
    case fourthly:
        greeting = 'five';
        break;
    case fifthly:
        greeting = 'one';
        break;    
    }
    
    h3.textContent = "Click " + greeting;
  }
}
```

```css
img {width:10%;}
```

```html
<div id="carousel_containerSL">
<div class="text14">                
<div id="slider3">
<div class="wrap">
<h3 class="captz"></h3>
<img id="three" draggable="false" src="http://www.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Facebook-icon-26.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott, I do appreciate you taking the time to find that code for me. 

I implemented the top with a <script></script> and the bottom replaced my original code within the body. 

I updated the "http://www.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Facebook-icon-26.png" with my 'images/COL1.jpg' file, as I presume this was what I was to replace also?

All this resulted in my buttons now not rotating and the word 'click' appearing underneath my picture box.... 

Please can you advise how I have misinterpreted your code?

I would like to thank you again for your time!

Comment: @Bertie No problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark this as the answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry @Scott, I think we commented at the same time and you did not see my question. Thanks again.